# Get value in textbox depending on combobox

Tags: vba

I have searched high and low for an answer to this. Lots of places come close to what I need but try as I might I can't find exactly what I need. So, here goes. I have a combo box on a user form that reads values from a table. when a user makes a selection, depending on how far down the table the selection falls, I would like a textbox to display one of two strings. I'm currently using a toggle button which seems a bit 'clunky. I'm fairly new to vba so be gentle with me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not quite what I was after. Let me try to explain it a little better. The combo box offers 24 choices from table 1, depending on the choice made the text box needs to show 1 of 2 options from table 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.textbox.Value = Me.combobox.Value
```

will give you the value of the **bounded column** of the selected row, usually the first one (e.g. if your combobox shows data like *ID;LastName;PreName*, it shows the ID)

If you want to show other colums than the bounded one, use

```
Me.textbox.Value = Me.combobox.Column(n)
```

(n stands for the column, beginning at 0 for the first, 1 for the second, ...)

So if you want to show the *LastName* of the previous example, go with

```
Me.textbox.Value = Me.combobox.Column(1)
```

If you just want to show the string when it doesn't fit in the combobox column, I'd make it like

```
If Len(Nz(Me.combobox.Column(1))) > n Then
    Me.textbox.Value = Me.combobox.Column(1)
Else
    Me.textbox.Value = Null
End If
```

There might be another solution, but this would be an easy one